# How to get average memory and CPU per process on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, process

Is there a tool which can help me getting average CPU and memory taken by a process by running over certain period of time? I used [Activity Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor), but this does not give average of these values.

Idea / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out iStat: http://bjango.com/apps/istatmenus/